# Clicking community promotion ad renders an instance of SO within the frame of that ad

Tags: bug, advertising, community-promotion-ads

Today I came across an ad on this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299219/how-to-replicate-vlookup-in-vba (I don't expect it to stay very long).

There was a community promotion ad on the right hand side of the site, I think for one of our English sites. It had a sentence that I only partially remember:

> Idiom ... poor or even poorer

I found it interesting, so I clicked that ad. Which caused a new instance of SO to open within the ad space. Unfortunately I failed to take a screenshot. I've been refreshing the page like crazy, but can't get the ad to appear again.

**Edit:**
I managed to get a new community add, for the photography site, and captured a screenshot:
[image]

**Edit2:**
This bug still persists, I saw it today with an OOP add from CodeReview, and an area 51 add.

Comment: Yep, [this has been happening for a while](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387296/clicking-on-the-stack-exchange-site-advertisement-in-the-side-bar-loads-the-sta).